# Which Claims should I use to map an ADFS user to GCIP

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, saml, adfs, google-identity

We have a SaaS product on the firebase platform, one of our customer asked us to provide a SSO experience to their users. They have an old ADFS as an IdP.

I though first to use Passport-Saml but then noticed that firebase auth could use Google Cloud Identity Platform for custom SAML IdP.

It worked pretty well and we got a user logged in first try. However, the user created in firebase is pretty empty.

Here is the user from the auth creation hook:

```json
 {
  customClaims: {
  }
  disabled: false   
  displayName: null   
  email: null   
  emailVerified: false   
  metadata: {
   creationTime: "2020-09-21T22:43:36Z"    
   lastSignInTime: "2020-09-21T22:43:36Z"    
  }
  passwordHash: null   
  passwordSalt: null   
  phoneNumber: null   
  photoURL: null   
  providerData: [
   0: {
    providerId: "saml.xxxx"     
    uid: "xxxx"     
   }
  ]
  tokensValidAfterTime: null   
  uid: "xxxx"   
 }
```

On the ADFS side, our customer has configured the claims to map LDAP as
E-mail-Addresses -> E-mail Address
SAM-Account-Name -> Name ID

If anyone has an idea on which SAML claim maps to firebase user attribute I would be very grateful, no luck in the doc.

**edit**
I created the ServiceProvider.xml using [saml tools](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
                     validUntil="2020-09-25T02:53:54Z"
                     cacheDuration="PT604800S"
                     entityID="xxxx">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                     Location="https://xxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"
                                     index="1" />
        
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

And did a bit more testing using [saml test](https://samltest.id/) which was a great sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is twofold:
The ServiceProvider.xml file needs to specify the nameid format as email address

```xml
 <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
```

And the claim mapping from ADFS needs to be
E-mail-Addresses -> Name ID